# How to animate a navigation bar large title while resizing bar?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

I have a `UITableViewController` embeded in a `UINavigationController`, with the property `navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles` set to `true`. As it would react normally, when you scroll the `tableView`, the navigation bar will shrink in size, and with it, the large title will get pushed behind the rest of the navigation bar, and a new small title will appear. What I want to do is to change this animation, to make the large title move to the center of the shrunk navigation bar and shrink in size. How could I do that?